# Checking if value already exist not working

Tags: php, mysql

I got an function that if you select an value in a dropdown menu my code updates a database with the selected value. Now i tried to add a check too check if the value already excists in the database. But it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

test.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script>
    function updateDb() {
     $.post("buh.php", $("#form").serialize());
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">    
    <?php
        include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
        $sql = "select * FROM sims ORDER BY phonenr asc"    ;
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);       
        $id1 = $_GET["id1"];
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='hidden' name='hidden' value='$id1'>";
        echo "<select id='select' name='select' onChange='updateDb()'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['phonenr'] . "'>" . $row['phonenr'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    ?>
    </form>
    <?php
    echo '<a href="javascript:window.close()">Sluit venster</a>';  
    ?>
<body>
```

Buh.php

```
<?php
include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
$sql = "select * FROM sims WHERE phonenr='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["select"])."'"  ;
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $id1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["hidden"]);
    $checkID = mysql_query("SELECT sim_id from pairings WHERE sim_id = '$id'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($checkID) > 0) {
       if(confirm("Simkaart is al gekoppeld weet u zeker dat u deze wilt vervangen?")){
        mysql_query("UPDATE pairings SET sim_id='$id' WHERE unit_id='$id1'")
        or die(mysql_error());   
        }
    }
    else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE pairings SET sim_id='$id' WHERE unit_id='$id1'")
            or die(mysql_error());   
    }
}
```

Comment: create a string with just the query. echo it. also you are not doing an "or die" with the select stmt, but just the update

Comment: What `confirm()` does on your PHP?

Comment: `confirm` is not a php function.is this your custom function?

Comment: There is a JavaScript confirm.

Comment: Do you want to avoid duplicates entirely into your database?

Comment: the same query regardless of the num_rows condition? o.O

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Apart from this being really, _really_, _rah-ha-heally_ terrible code – doing it this way you have a TOCTTOU problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOCTTOU), so you would at least have to encapsulate this into a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing

```
 if(confirm("Simkaart is al gekoppeld weet u zeker dat u deze wilt vervangen?")){
```

To a a javascript function

Thanks!